# Format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'int', any mistake I made here?

Tags: c, debugging

There is some error in my code, anyone can help with debugging? Apparently, there is something wrong at the `scanf` part to get my `x`.
The instructions are as shown below:

This program is a simple introductory of C language application that involves console display, user input, strings, and loops.
Write codes that will produce the screen as shown:

Firstly, the program prompts the user to enter his or her name.
Then, it will display

```
Hello <user name>
```

Next, it prints out a menu which contains 4 options:

1. add two integers
2. add two strings
3. compute factorial for integer less and including `10` or less than `11`
4. quit program

Code all 4 tasks appropriately.

When the task is completed (not including quitting program of course), the menu pops up again and asks the user to try on another task. This repeat until <kbd>q</kbd> or <kbd>Q</kbd> is pressed. You may use **switch- case** or **if-else**, but the former looks more legible.
Even though you may know how to write functions, do not use functions in this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char name[20],
     c[1000],
     d[1000],
     x;
int a, b, i, n,
    factorial = 1;

int main() {
    do {
        printf("\nPlease select one:\n");
        printf("**********MENU**********\n");
        printf("1 - add two integers\n");
        printf("2 - add two strings\n");
        printf("3 - compute factorial for integer less and including 10 or less than 11\n");
        printf("Q - quit program\n");
        printf("************************\n");

        scanf("%s", x);

        switch(x) {

        case '1':
            printf("Enter first integer:\n");
            scanf("%d", &a);
            printf("Enter second integer:\n");
            scanf("%d", &b);
            printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, a + b);
            break;
        case '2':
            printf("Enter first string:\n");
            scanf("%s", c);
            printf("Enter second string:\n");
            scanf("%s", d);
            strcat(c, d);
            printf("%s\n", c);
            break;
        case '3':
            printf("Enter integer less than 11:\n");
            scanf("%d", &n);
            if (n > 0 && n < 11) {
                for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
                    factorial *= i;
                }
                printf("factorial of %d is %d\n", n, factorial);
                break;
            }
            else {
                printf("error, please enter an integer\n");
            }

        case 'Q':
            printf("Program quitting...\n");
            break;

        }
    } while (x != 'Q');
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",x);` you can't store a string in the space of a single char.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Which doesn't even matter, because storing into a single char would still require passing its address.

Comment: Suggest `x[1024]` and then using `fgets(x, sizeof x, stdin);` to read the selection and then `switch (*x) {...}`. (and don't forget to check the return of ***every*** input function used)

Comment: or use scanf("%c",&x)

Answer (score 1):

`x` is declared as a character here.

```
char name[20],
     c[1000],
     d[1000],
     x;
```

But when scanning into `x` you use `%s`, which is for Strings.

```
scanf("%s", &x);
```

The correct way to scan a character is `scanf("%c",&x);`

Also, don't forget your import statements and your `return 0;` at the end of the program.

Comment: you'll need to use &x;

Comment: "import statements"? Did you mean `#include` directives?

Comment: yup! I've been doing too much Java recently.